# How does ADR work?

Tags: dialogue, production

How does ADR (Automated Dialogue Replacement) work?  There's an entry in Wikipedia that says what it is (essentially actors dubbing their lines in post production, sometimes requiring several takes) but I don't see what's "automatic" about it.  It doesn't seem to work all that well because I can almost always tell when it has been used.

Comment: The term "automated" is not really appropriate for the actual action, to be honest. I'm guessing there's a historic reason for it but the process is far from automated.

Comment: 'Automated' is not equivalent to 'automatic'. 'Automated' indicates some processing took place to superimpose the newly-recorded words. There is some (little) expectation that it is seamless and undetectable. Maybe the detection you have is because TOO MUCH play was afforded the section making it seem too processed in the midst of the natural scene.

Comment: I can also tell when ADR has been used in many cases, even when the quality and the budget of the movie is impressive and I'm disappointed. Not sure why it's called "automated" though.

Comment: I want to point out that much of the movie Twister (with Helen Hunt and Bill Paxton) was ADR, but I couldn't tell. I do notice it in some other movies and shows though. And like everyone else commenting on this, I don't know where the "automated" part of it comes from.

Comment: @wbogacz But I can see how it *could* be automated; as you were suggesting.  A computer could input the original dialogue from the soundtrack, separate out the words (if our smart phones can do that, an expensive computer should do an even better job); then repeat for the words spoken by the actor and line them up by stretching or reducing a little of the time between the actor's words.  Come on Hollywood, not that difficult.

Comment: Yeah... not difficult if you want it to sound like Siri or the lady who does the voice prompting when you call companies.

Comment: @wbogacz *"automated is not equivalent to automatic"* Actually, the first entry in [Collins Thesaurus](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/automated?showCookiePolicy=true) for automated is automatic.

Comment: Related: [Do movie actors/actresses dub their scenes after shooting or do they use the audio that is in the scene?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/26784/13595).

Comment: Is "automated" even the correct word? I also see "Additional Dialogue Recording" as an explanation, which makes more sense.

Comment: I think 'additional' came first, the others [automated, automatic] since the technology was further developed. As it is pretty much only ever referred to by the initials ADR, I'm not sure anyone in the business even considers what the A stands for any more.. it's like that moment you have to suddenly remember what USB actually means .. or DVD .. is it video, or versatile... & do you actually care so long as it works? ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would be hugely surprised if you can actually **always** tell when ADR has been used - your point re a computer automatically cutting & shuffling time is precisely how modern ADR is done, using a new recording of the actor talking over his old lines - then chopped & shuffled in such a way that it is literally impossible to tell that the lip sync is not 'real'

In that situation, the only giveaway would be if the sound department failed to successfully drop the new audio nicely into the foley track - if they got the room reverb wrong, etc - highly unlikely on a high budget production.

Examples of software to specifically do this task
* [VocAlign Pro](http://www.synchroarts.co.uk/products/vocalign-pro/overview) [This is the one I used to use, 20 years ago - things have moved on since, but the page has audio/video demos so you can see how the process works]
* [ADRStudio](http://www.gallery.co.uk)
* [VirtualVTR](http://www.virtualvtr.com/vtrpro.html)
* [VoiceQ](http://voiceq.com/voiceq2/)

There are also some seriously expensive hardware solutions, from people like [SoundMaster](http://www.soundmaster.com/index.html)

BTW, just because automated & automatic are almost synonymous does not mean they are actually exactly the same thing.
The process may be automated [processed by machine], but it is not automatic [done with no human intervention].