# Where does the automated/automatic come from in ADR?

Tags: dialogue, production, terminology

I know there are recent advancements in software that allow for automatic/automated dialogue replacement but in films that predate this technology they still use the same terminology and as far as I know it was a completely manual process.

Where did this terminology originate, and what is so automatic/automated about manually dubbing over voices?

Comment: [Similar question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/34851/how-does-adr-work).

Comment: The automatic refers either to not having to reshoot the scene, or that its done digitally instead of manually splicing film/tape. Since I can't say this is authoritative, comment instead of answer:

Comment: `Historically, film stock was spliced into a loop of the segment of the dialog being replaced and this segment was interlocked to an audio recording device. The actor would then watch the picture and listen to the sync sound while repeating the phrase ad nauseum until the director was satisfied the take was perfect. This has been replaced (except the "ad nauseum" part) by computerized workstations which greatly enhance the workflow as well as giving distinct advantages to further post production audio work such as "sweetening".`

Comment: @Catija - [similar question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/34851/how-does-adr-work/41498#41498) now has an answer, too. The 'ad nauseum' has been significantly reduced in recent years ;)

Comment: BTW, It used to be called 'looping', after the process of cutting the film into loops & repeating the same lines over & over until everyone was happy or the actor was hoarse. It's only been called ADR since the process could be automated to some extent.

Comment: @cde link please?

Comment: Google the quote. But it is essentially just that before it goes into modern adr techniques